# Replace Null value to infinite

Tags: mysql, database, select, where-clause, between

I have a table with field min, max and amount.
The last value of the column max is always null and it denotes min value and above as per my logic.
During BETWEEN query in sql I tried as:

```
 Select t.amount from my_table t where 25000 between t.min and NVL(t.max, ~0);
```

Also, I tried:

```
 Select t.amount  from my_table t where 25000 between t.min and COALESCE(t.max, ~0);
```

None of them return me a row if the value lies between min and NULL.

The sample Data is :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain that I completely glean what you are trying to do here, but I sense that you want logic for dealing with unknown max values in your table, and these unknown values are represented by `NULL`.  Assuming you want to query under the assumption that an unknown max value means just don't restrict by max, then use:

```
SELECT amount
FROM my_table
WHERE min <= 25000 AND (max >= 25000 OR max IS NULL);
```

If `max` happens to be `NULL`/unknown, then only a minimum restriction would be applied.  See the demo below.

### Demo

Comment: The value to be compared is a dynamic value and I need to get only one amount. This may return me 2 rows if smaller value is passed to compare.

Comment: Great.  But that's another question, and you should back it with some actual sample data.

Comment: I have added some sample. Have look at it. The task is if I send any value above 20001 I need output as 200.

Comment: My query already meets your requirements.  [See the running demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdbb8915f1bb7d4b72901364ebf3e548).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
25000 between t.min and nvl(t.max, 25000)
```

If `t.max` is null, the `nvl()` function returns `25000`, which will satisfy the higher bound of the `between` operator.

If the value to compare is stored in a column, say `col1`, then you can do:

```
col1 between t.min and nvl(t.max, col1)
```

Comment: I need the replacement for the max value as the infinite. As the value to be compared may be any larger value.

Comment: @SudipBolakhe: where does the value to compare comes from? If it is stored in a column, say `col1`, then you can do: `col1 between t.min and nvl(t.max, col1)`